# Update annotations loaded with http

Tags: swift, http, annotations, swift3, mkmapview

I am loading some GeoData from my server and want to display them throw annotations:

```
Alamofire.request("http://localhost:1234/app/data").responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        let json = JSON(value)
        var annotations = [Station]()
        for (key, subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
            let lat: CLLocationDegrees = subJson["latitude"].double! as CLLocationDegrees
            let long: CLLocationDegrees = subJson["longtitude"].double! as CLLocationDegrees
            self.annotations += [Station(name: "test", lat: lat, long: long)]
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let allAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations
            self.mapView.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)
            self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
        }

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

and my `Station` class:

```
class Station: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var identifier = "test"
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(name:String, lat:CLLocationDegrees, long:CLLocationDegrees) {
        title = name
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    }
}
```

So what I did, is basically:

Load data from remote service and display these data as annotations on `MKMapView`.

But: somehow these annotations are not loaded on the map, even i first "remove" and next "add" them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you set breakpoints in your response, do all of your JSON values print as expected? Does it hit each section of the method in the order that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your `Station` instances to some `self.annotations` property, not your local variable, `annotations`. Thus, `annotations` local var is still just that empty array.

Obviously, you can fix that by referencing `annotations` rather than `self.annotations`:

```
var annotations = [Station]()
for (key, subJson): (String, JSON) in json {
    let lat = ...
    let long = ...
    annotations += [Station(name: "test", lat: lat, long: long)] // not `self.annotations`
}
```

Or you can use `map`, avoiding this potential confusion altogether:

```
let annotations = json.map { key, subJson -> Station in
    Station(name: "test", lat: subJson["latitude"].double!, long: subJson["longitude"].double!)
}
```